using LMS class file
The document class of London Mathematical Society lms isn't available at CTAN and so it can't be part of any TeX distribution. I downloaded the template from this website https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex209/contrib/lms/lmsguide.tex.
When I run the tex, it cannot work.
How to solve this problem?

This is a document style from 1995 (aimed at LaTeX 2.09 not LaTeX2e) - I'd say 'do not use' is the only sensible answer

But I cannot find the LMS template from other websites. Do you know the download link?

Reading the LMS site, they don't specify any particular class - I advise contacting the appropriate editorial office for details, but suspect you can just use article

I am afraid that the  length of the article does not meet the standard. So I need to run the LMS template to check the pages of the article.

You should ask the Society for information. The most I can offer is that the sample document in the distribution compiles flawlessly.

@mathbeginner You are assuming they have a template for the typeset journal: there's no reason to think that's true

Did you recognize at https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex209/contrib/lms/ that these are from 1995? Contacting LMS is the way to go, in my view ... // See also e.g. here https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-journal-of-the-london-mathematical-society-lms/rggmkdznnsbj AND here: https://www.lms.ac.uk/publications/au-instructions

I tried to use this template.overleaf.com/latex/templates/…. But it also cannot work.

Undefined contral sequence?
